# How would I write a triangle function recursively?

Tags: haskell

So I am trying to write a recursive function where you can input a triangle number e.g. 5 and it will return the answer 15. I can use this to output the correct answer:

```
triangle n = n * (n + 1) `div` 2
```

But how could I do this recursively?

Comment: Why would you want to do it recursively?

Comment: Well ive just started learning recursion and this was something i came across that would be interesting to see how it could be done

Comment: Thinking this way is a solution looking for a problem, not the other way around.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
triangle 0 = 0
triangle n = n + triangle (n-1)
```

But why?

Comment: Because you want to! Because you want to! [Er, sorry about that...]

Answer (score -1):

```
triangle :: Integer -> Integer
triangle n = recTriangle n 0
    where
      recTriangle 0 acc = acc
      recTriangle n2 acc = recTriangle (n2-1) (acc+n2)
```

If you want tail recursion, this is it. (Your initial attempt is still better.)